# Renewing/Refreshing Express Session

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies, passport.js, session-timeout

In my app I restrict some access to some actions and pages if a user is not logged in. I have:

```
var restrict = function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.user) {
      console.log("USER isn't logged in.")
      return res.status(403).send('Access or action denied, please log in'); 
    }
    next();
}


app.get('/stocks', restrict, MainHandler.findAllStocksFromUser);
app.get('/stocks/:id', MainHandler.findStockByIdAndDates);
app.put('/stocks/:id/stockActions', restrict, MainHandler.handleStockAction);
```

I'm essentially trying to refresh a session everytime the client makes a request to the server so that the server doesn't logout the user/destroy the session when it shouldn't. For testing, I want the session to expire/the user to be logged out if 20 seconds go by without the user making an requests to the server. I have:

```
    app.use(session({secret: 'secret', saveUninitialized: true, resave: true, expires: new Date(Date.now() + (20000))}));
```

Then I try to use middleware to refresh the expiration date every time the use makes a request:

```
// Session-persisted message middleware
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  req.session.cookie.expires = new Date(Date.now() + 20000);
  next();
});
```

But if I log in from the client, and click around, causing requests to the server, I still get the log-in error on the client after 20 seconds, despite trying to "refresh" the session in the middleware. I have also tried using maxAge using the same strategy with the middleware. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You could try to use https://github.com/expressjs/session#sessionregenerate

Answer (score 12):

You can try define your session as follows

```
app.use (
   session ({
      secret: "secret",
      saveUninitialized: true,
      resave: true,
      cookie: {
         expires: 20 * 1000
      }
   })
);
```

and then refresh the session using

```
req.session.touch()
```

or you could define your session as

```
app.use (
   session ({
      secret: "secret",
      saveUninitialized: false,
      resave: true,
      rolling: true,
      cookie: {
         expires: 20 * 1000
      }
   })
);
```

and it will renew the session automatically and it will only expire when it has been idle for the value in the expires variable

Answer (score 6):

`express-session` supports a duration-based [`maxAge`](https://github.com/expressjs/session#cookiemaxage) setting, which will work better than setting a fixed date for all sessions. So your middleware usage should instead look like:

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true,
  maxAge: 20000
}));
```

Next, to update the expiration of the session, you can just call [`req.session.touch();`](https://github.com/expressjs/session#sessiontouch) if that is all you're doing to the session and its contents.

The [documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/session) has a lot of other good information on controlling session expiration and related topics.

Comment: This isn't working for me. If i print req.session.maxAge to the console on each request I get 'undefined'. So I tried doing app.use(session({secret: 'secret', saveUninitialized: true, resave: true, cookie: {maxAge: 20000}})); instead and req.session.touch() isn't seeming to work because the session still stops after 20 seconds regardless of how many requests I make

Comment: @gcc Did you get any solutions to this??

Comment: I think you have to use req.session.cookie.maxAge